# How to re-play Lottie animation in React Native

Tags: react-native, lottie

I'm trying to use 'react-native-app-intro-slider' with Lottie animations.

It works well, but when I click Back or Next button, the animation stops playing.

How can I re-play the animations?

Thanks in advance!

```
const renderItem = ({ item }) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}> 
      <LottieView
        ref={LottieRef}
        autoPlay
        loop
        source={item.lottie}
      />
    </View>
  </ImageBackground>
)}

const slideChange = () => {
  LottieRef.current.play(); // it doesn't work
}

useEffect(() => {
  if (LottieRef.current !== null) {
    LottieRef.current.play(); // it doesn't work
  }
}, [LottieRef])

...

<AppIntroSlider 
   renderItem={renderItem} 
   data={slides} 
   onDone={onDone}
   onSlideChange={slideChange}
   showSkipButton
   showPrevButton
/>
```

Comment: I've tried to re-create this, but with loop and autoplay set to true, the animations keeps repeating as expected. https://snack.expo.io/@nipuna777/app-intro-slider-with-lottie

Are there additional changes required?

Comment: @nipuna777 thanks for the reply. What I wanted to ask was the animations didn't keep repeating when I click 'back' button (or swipe to the left). With my device(android), the same thing happens in your Snack (animation works well but does not work for previous slider pages)

Comment: Hmm that looks like a bug. I bumped up to the latest version and that fixes the issue on iOS. But to fix it on Android, I had to force a re-render on slide change. You can look at the updated snack to see if that's a workable solution for you.

Comment: @nipuna777 wow it works perfect! Thank you so much you are a genius!

Answer (score 1):

Had same issue recently. If you don't want to use ref approach you can use old trick of setting key property on the LottieView which should be related to the source so when that source is changing key property will receive a new value and React will re-render it, e.g.

```
<LottieView
    // other props you might need
    key={item.id}
    source={item.lottie}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `.play()` to componentDidMount or in useEffect in order to play the animation on each component mount.

You could do something similar to this

```
import React from 'react';
import LottieView from 'lottie-react-native';
 
export default class BasicExample extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.animation.play();
    // Or set a specific startFrame and endFrame with:
    this.animation.play(30, 120);
  }
 
  render() {
    return (
      <LottieView
        ref={animation => {
          this.animation = animation;
        }}
        source={require('../path/to/animation.json')}
      />
    );
  }
}
```